# Gnome 3 notiofication about suspend when suspend is disabled (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, sleep, gnome, gnome3

I've disabled all kinds of suspension with `sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`. After a while I'm getting Gnome 3 notification:

> Automatic suspend
>
> Computer will suspend very soon because of inactivity.

It never does, but the notification irritates me. How can Ii turn suspend off in Gnome 3 on Debian? In GUI power saving options there are only options regarding screen blanking.

Comment: On mine, the suspend options are at the bottom of "Power" section of the GNOME Control Center. Don't you have it there?